# Power BI Toggle: How to Ensure Returning to Previous Drill-Through Selection?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerapps, drillthrough

I've developed a design concept for a **Project Management Dashboard**. It incorporates a hierarchy of Portfolio Overview, Programs, Projects, and Project Details. Users can select a specific program from a table visual listing various programs and perform a drill-through action by clicking a button. The selected program then acts as a filter for the page they land on after the drill-through. On the Program Detail page, users see the current program displayed as a card, with all associated projects listed in a table.

However, if a user wants to navigate directly to the program level using the page navigation, I've implemented a toggle that clears the filter set by the drill-through. This allows users to view all projects across all programs, and the title, which used to be the name of the previously selected program, changes to "All Projects". When I click the toggle again, I want to return to viewing the individual program filtered during the drill-through. This functionality is achieved through bookmarks.

However, when I use the toggle to return to the individual program view, it always goes back to the program set **when I created the bookmark**.

I want the toggle to **always return me to the individual program I had selected previously**, rather than the one set when creating the bookmark. How can I achieve this?

I have scoured through many forums and searched videos, hoping to find a similar issue described and potential solutions. However, it appears that my use case is quite specific, as I have been unable to find any answers or approaches to resolve it so far.